# Pass a collection from component to flow

Tags: visual-workflow, collection

I have one request to pass a List of records from Lightning Component to a Flow.

this is the attribute which holds my variables:

```
<aura:attribute name="AgreementLineItems" type="Apttus__AgreementLineItem__c[]"/>
```

This is where the flow is on the component:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.showFlow}">Save</button>
        <aura:set attribute="else"> <!-- else part of aura:if isTrue="{!v.isFirstPage}" just to switch pages and only show this flow-->
            <lightning:flow aura:id="businessInformation"/>
        </aura:set>
```

This is where the flow is being called:

```
showFlow: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isFirstPage", false);
        var flow = component.find("businessInformation");        
        
        var inputVariables = [
            { name : "ListFromComponent", type : "List", value: component.get("v.AgreementLineItems") },
            { name : "LaunchedFromComponent", type : "Boolean", value: true }            
        ];
        
        flow.startFlow("demo", inputVariables);     
        
    },
```

On the flow, this is my Collection variable:
[image]

Also my other variable:
[image]

This is the flow:
[image]

test node which contains the component:
[image]

and Title 2 component which is just to display the variables for testing:
[image]

When the button is pressed that triggers the showFlow method, this error appears:
[image]

If I comment the second line that sets the collection variable it works, however without the main purpose of it:

```
var inputVariables = [
        //{ name : "ListFromComponent", type : "List", value: component.get("v.AgreementLineItems") },
        { name : "LaunchedFromComponent", type : "Boolean", value: true }            
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the commented line, change the type from **List** to **SObject**...and done! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing the type from List to SObject on this line:
{ name : "ListFromComponent", type : "List", value: component.get("v.AgreementLineItems") },